# How to redefine variable value and use value to other method in class PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I can't get value variable in a method, after use this value to another method in one class PHP Laravel.

```
public function paymentCourse(Request $request)
{

    $idCourse = $request->input('idcourse');
    $CoursePrice = Course::where('id', $idCourse)->first();

    if(Auth::user()->palate) {

        if(Auth::user()->palate->is_palate == 1) {
             // this value I want to transfer method getTransactionAmount()
            $currentPrice = $CoursePrice->price_palate;
        }

    } else {
         // this value I want to transfer method getTransactionAmount()
        $currentPrice = $CoursePrice->price;
    }

    return view('pages.payment-course', compact('currentPrice'));

}



public function getTransactionAmount($type) {

    switch ($type) {
        case 'palate':
            return 11645;
            break;
        case 'course':            
            return 15000; // I get value method paymentCourse() $currentPrice.
            break;
        case 'course_sale':                
            return 12000; // I get value method paymentCourse() $currentPrice.
            break;
        default:
            throw new \Exception('Wrong transaction type');
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the issue exactly?

Comment: store the value in sessions and use in other method

Comment: Tried to override properties in a class: 

"public $currentPrice;" after call in  $this->currentPrice = $currentPrice = $CoursePrice->price_palate; 

after I call in method getTransactionAmount() return $this->currentPrice;  but, dd($this->currentPrice) function display null.

Comment: You're not handling when `(Auth::user()->palate->is_palate == 1)` is falsy?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, thank you for help.

```
public function paymentCourse(Request $request)
{

    $idCourse = $request->input('idcourse');
    $CoursePrice = Course::where('id', $idCourse)->first();

    if(Auth::user()->palate) {

        if(Auth::user()->palate->is_palate == 1) {
            $currentPrice = $CoursePrice->price_palate;
            \Session::put('currentPrice', $currentPrice);
        }

    } else {
        $currentPrice = $CoursePrice->price;
        \Session::put('currentPrice', $currentPrice);
    }


    return view('pages.payment-course', compact('currentPrice'));

}

private function getTransactionAmount($type) {

    $currentPrice = \Session::get('currentPrice');

    switch ($type) {
        case 'palate':
            return 11645;
            break;
        case 'course':
            return $currentPrice;
            break;
        case 'course_sale':
            return $currentPrice;
            break;
        default:
            throw new \Exception('Wrong transaction type');
    }

}
```